# Load certificate chain from PEM file into STACK_OF(X509)* using OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, pem

Working with the OpenSSL library in c, what is the best way to load a complete certificate chain from a PEM file into memory? The input is a single PEM file with 1..n certificates concatenated, the output should be a `STACK_OF(X509)*`.

For single certificates, the easiest way to load them is as follows:

```
SSL_CTX *sslctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, "certificate.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(sslctx);
X509 *crt = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);
```

(error handling, resource freeing and reference counting omitted for clarity; using C99 syntax; "easy" meaning "avoiding lower level BIO and ASN.1 APIs")

However, for complete certificate chains, `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` can be used to load them into the `SSL_CTX` and the first certificate can then be retrieved using `SSL_get_certificate()`, but there seems to be no [API function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html) to retrieve the rest of the certificate chain from an `SSL` context.

So what is the best way to load a certificate chain from a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` puts the certificate into `SSL_CTX::cert` and all additional certificates in the chain (additional CA cetrificates) into `SSL_CTX::extra_certs` which type is `STACK_OF(X509)*`, so to get your additional chain:

```
STACK_OF(X509)* ca_stack = sslctx->extra_certs;
```

I could not find any macro or function that can give you the `extra_cets` field without accessing it directly in `SSL_CTX` structure, but looking at the OpenSSL code they do access it directly everywhere.

Comment: FTR, OpenSSL 1.0.2 finally introduced SSL_CTX_get0_chain_certs() to access the additional certificates.

Comment: I could not get this to work for me. I had a chain that openssl recognized on the command line, `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` would load it without errors, but then `extra_certs` would be empty! I ended up loading the file into memory, parsing it to split it into chunks, and loading each cert manually using `PEM_read_bio_X509`. :(